# How to recode into a new variable and add it to the tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working with tidyverse and I cannot get the proper function (code) to recode a variable into a new variable and then add that to the tibble

I use mutate and I get the new variable when I run select, but I do not see the column in my data frame and I cannot get results for the new variable when applying class, levels or summary commands. I only receive the message:

Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ownership'.

```
     final %>%
        mutate(ownership = recode(protaxcoderec,
                        "0" = "Rental",
                        "1" = "Owner Occupied",
                        .default = "NA"))
```

Here is a sample of the data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb4Qu.png)

Comment: Would you share your code with us?? Maybe an example of your data too...
Because commonly `df %>% mutate( YourVar = NewVar) -> df` or `df <- df %>% mutate( YourVar = NewVar)` or `df %<>% mutate( YourVar = NewVar)` should work.

Comment: Hello, I jut added the code I am using an a sample of the data

Comment: I think you want to use a `case_when`. Switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well. Then you may use `dplyr::case_when`.

If `protaxcoderec == 1` then `ownership == "Owner Occupied"`, 
If `protaxcoderec == 0` then `ownership == "Rental"`

```
 final %>%
        mutate(ownership = case_when(
                        protaxcoderec == 0 ~ "Rental",
                        protaxcoderec == 1 ~ "Owner Occupied",
                        TRUE ~ NA_character_ ))
```

Comment: I run that code and I get a tibble in the console with an extra column, but why when I run class or level using ownership it gives me the warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ownership' ? should I be performing another step in order to be able to run those other functions? and why I do not see an extra variable in the table in the environment window?

Comment: Hello, I solved it using your code. What I did was just to create a new data set: final2 <- final%>% ... and I got a new data set where I was able to perform other functions with the new variable. Not sure this is how people usually works in the rstudio environment whne creating new (recoding) variable. Me coming from spss it was just simply to recode into a new variable and the variable automatically appearers at the end of the data view.  Thanks @Aureliano